# Look for a specific label in Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-vision

I am using Google's cloud vision API to detect "smile" in photos submitted. However, I am not able to find a way to specifically specify this. Currently am getting smile among several other labels that are returned.

Is there a way to detect a specific label via this API? My request body looks somewhat like below:

```
[{
         "image" : {
           "content": base64img
           },
           "features": [{
              "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
              "maxResults": 10
           }]
}]
```

The response am getting is as below:

```
0 : {mid: "/m/0dzct", description: "face", score: 0.9535997, topicality: 0.9535997}
1 : {mid: "/m/0k0pj", description: "nose", score: 0.86705405, topicality: 0.86705405}
2 : {mid: "/m/04hgtk", description: "head", score: 0.8595986, topicality: 0.8595986}
3 : {mid: "/m/01kyr8", description: "darkness", score: 0.8346672, topicality: 0.8346672}
4 : {mid: "/m/0gjyk", description: "phenomenon", score: 0.7547649, topicality: 0.7547649}
5 : {mid: "/m/0dgw9r", description: "human", score: 0.73061824, topicality: 0.73061824}
6 : {mid: "/m/019nj4", description: "smile", score: 0.6036549, topicality: 0.6036549}
7 : {mid: "/m/01d74z", description: "night", score: 0.56837195, topicality: 0.56837195}
8 : {mid: "/m/0ds5b", description: "facial hair", score: 0.56621134, topicality: 0.56621134}
9 : {mid: "/m/01kv7h", description: "midnight", score: 0.5530265, topicality: 0.5530265}
```

I am forced to add higher maxResults value as am not sure where Smile will get listed.

Comment: You could iterate through the list of labels provided the Google Vision API and check if the desired labels are there in the list.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are looking to achieve here. Are you interested in getting a yes or no response to the question "is there a smile in the picture"? If so, you can discard the maxResults field and then check whether the "smile" description is listed at all in the response. You might want to add some more logic, as in, to check whether "smile" is returned and has a score greater than some threshold.